# Named-Named method/function arguments

Tags: python, function, methods, arguments, named

How can I use 'variable'-based named arguments.. better explained by example :

```
def blah(var, a=None, b=None, c=None): ...
```

more precise it is :

```
def blah(var, **kwargs): ...
```

I want to be able to do :

```
named = 'b'
blah(55, named=66)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
blah(55, b=66)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the argument(s) in a `dict` and pass the argument(s) via `**` unpacking as keyword arguments.

```py
named = 'b'
kwargs = {named: 66}
blah(55, **kwargs)
```